# resizing button size based on number of items

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my Angular app. I am trying to render buttons in my view using *ngFor directive. I want the rendered buttons side by side. I am able to do it. I want to resize the button base on the number of buttons.
For example:
If i have 4 buttons i want each button to have 25% width
If i have 2 buttons i want each button to have 50% width
If i have 1 buttons i want each button to have 100% width

How can i achieve it. please guide me.

HTML

```
<nb-card>
<div class="col-md-12" >
  <div class="col-md-3 pt-5" *ngFor="let data of TestData">
    <nb-card class="testCard">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [value]="data.test[0]" readonly>
        <div>
            <input type="button" *ngFor="let ts of data.test[1]"  class="form-control testButton" (click)="onClick(ts.id)" [value]="ts.foo" readonly>
        </div>
    </nb-card>
  </div>
</div>
</nb-card>
```

css

```
.testButton {
display: display: inline-block;
width: 25%
// if i mention width 25% only. I am able to render the buttons side by side. otherwise it renders width width 100% and not side by side.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned befor, you can use flexbox, it is the more elegant way.
But since you are intrested in the Angular way, you should use the ngStyle directive:

```
<nb-card>
  <div class="col-md-12" >
    <div class="col-md-3 pt-5" *ngFor="let data of TestData">
      <nb-card class="testCard">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [value]="data.test[0]" readonly>
          <div>
              <input type="button" *ngFor="let ts of data.test[1]"  class="form- 
 control testButton" (click)="onClick(ts.id)" [value]="ts.foo" readonly
  [ngStyle]="{'width':(100 / data.test[1].length) + '%'}">
          </div>
      </nb-card>
    </div>
  </div>
  </nb-card>
```

using the ngStyle directive gives you the poswer to calc the desired width from inside the DOM based on your data.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't using flexbox:

```
<input type="button" [style.width.%]="100/data.test[1].length">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) in CSS on the button container for this.
Literally this is all you need:

```
input[type='text'] div {
    display: flex;
}
```